# Power BI Relationship Guidance

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have two tables with the following type of data:

TABLE 1:
Region Count of approvals  [This graphic is from data in table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkl0R.png)
NAM 4
LATAM   1
Canada  1
EMEA    2
APAC    0

Table 2:
Activity   Regions Involved
1          Canada
2          Nam, Canada, LATAM
3          EMEA, APAC
4          EMEA
5          NAM
6          APAC, LATAM
8          NAM, EMEA

What I want is for Table 2 to filter when I check on the bar in the graphic.  So if the "NAM" bar was clicked then Table 2 would filter for Activities, 2,5,8.

I created a relationship of "many to many" for the "Region" column in table 1 and "Regions Involved" in Table 2.

With that I got table 2 to filter to show activity 5 only.  Basically only things that are exact matches.

I tried to change the relationship to "One to Many" and got an error that "Table 1 didn't have unique values".  There is only 5 values in the column, although there are some blanks below in Table 1.

Thoughts?

Thanks!